# Moving pointers memory allocation from main() to function and using pointer in other functions

Tags: c, pointers, memory

Hey I'm trying to move pointer memory allocation `d =(deque*)malloc(sizeof(deque));` into first function called `void initDeque()`. I tried leaving declaration in `main` and allocating memory in the function, but program just crashes after initializing the deque and I can't use the pointer in other functions.

Here's the code:

```
int main(){
    int x;
    deque *d;
    d = (deque*)malloc(sizeof(deque));

    initDeque(d);
    putFront(d,10);
```

And the function where I want to move memory allocation for pointer:

```
void initDeque(deque *d){ //Create new deque
    //d = (deque*)malloc(sizeof(deque));
    printf("Initializing deque\n");
    d->front=NULL;
    d->rear=NULL;
}
```

Program runs great if declaration and allocation is in the `main()`, but it crashes when I put allocation into `void initDeque`.

Comment: [Thou shalt not cast the result of malloc in C, else there will be much wailing and gnashing of teeth.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments (even pointers) are [passed by value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) in C.

So return the pointer:

```
deque *make_queue(){ //Create new deque
  deque *d = malloc(sizeof(deque));
  if (!d) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
  printf("Initializing deque\n");
  d->front=NULL;
  d->rear=NULL;
  return d;
}
```

and call `d = make_queue();` in start of your your `main`; when doing a `malloc` *always test for failure*.

Alternatively, pass the address of a pointer, as [answered by clcto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29105328/841108)

Read wikipage on [C dynamic memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation). Don't forget to call `free` appropriately. For debugging, use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) if available. Avoid [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) (and double `free`-s). When you are more mature in C, read the wikipage on [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29), perhaps consider using in some cases [Boehm conservative garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/).

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to pass a pointer to the pointer:

```
int main()
{
    deque *d;
    initDeque( &d );
}

void initDeque( deque **d )
{
    *d = malloc( sizeof( deque ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When calling the function you are sending the values in the d variable as argument to the function instead of its pointer (aka memory address).

```
initDeque(d);
```

In order to send the pointer itself you must send its memory address instead:

```
initDeque(&d);
```

For this I would also advise you to use a pointer of a pointer, this way you can send the address you are pretending to allocate the data even if you haven't used memalloc already.

The value of &d will be a memory address if  you try to display it so make sure you remember its a pointer of a pointer later.